# Use settings.json file with Node.js and pkg

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm currently trying to make my Node.js app into an executable using pkg, but I have encountered a problem. My app depends on a separate file called `settings.json` where vital settings are defined by the user. My app successfully gathers the information from `settings.json` when I run the Node app from command line, but the `.exe` variant made with pkg doesn't seem to follow the `settings.json`, instead it always follows the content `settings.js` that existed once the .exe was created.

The settings.json is imported like this in my js file:

```
const settings = require('./settings.json');
```

I have included this under pkg in package.json:

```
"pkg": {
    "assets": [
        "./node_modules/boxen/**",
        "./node_modules/chalk/**",
        "./node_modules/cheerio/**",
        "./node_modules/htmlparser2/**",
        "./node_modules/moment/**",
        "./node_modules/request/**"
    ]
  }
```

These are the dependencies that need to bundled with the `.exe`, but I have not included the `settings.json` here which is why I wonder why the `.exe` variant isn't reading from the `settings.json` file that's in the same directory.

Thanks for any input on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` is evaluated at build time. If you want to get the JSON at run time then you'll need to [read the file](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) and then [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it yourself.

Comment: Does build, in this instance, refer to when the executable is built and not when the executable is launched? Because the settings in the JSON only need to be read when the app launches, it doesn't need to detect changes to the JSON while the app is running.

Comment: Yes, when the executable is built.